# Ionic Emulate iOS/Android command not working

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Context: I am currently on Ionic version 3.15.2. The 'ionic serve' command works. The 'ionic cordova emulate ios' and 'ionic cordova emulate android' do not work. I have tried deleting/reinstalling certain packages and dependencies from Ionic but nothing has helped. I have a feeling I need to delete/reinstall Xcode all together but I figured I would ask for help here first. This is the error message I get on my terminal when I try to use the Ionic simulator/emulator:

> Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
>
> CodeSign build/emulator/****app.app
>
> (1 failure)
>
> Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args:
>   -xcconfig,/Users/*****/Desktop/*****/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,****app.xcworkspace,-scheme,****app,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS
>   Simulator,name=iPhone
>   5s,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/*****/Desktop/****/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/****/Desktop/****/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova emulate ios (exit code 1).

Note: I used the asterisks in place of the path for privacy reasons

It's weird that `ionic serve` works but the other two commands don't...

Answer (score 0):

Even `ionic info` should fail with the latter error.

It's because of the module `@ionic/cli-plugin-proxy`. As soon as I uninstalled it I could successfully run `ionic info`. But it detected `IONIC_HTTP_PROXY` in my environment and asked me to install it again.
So I did manually later, but the error returned. So I installed the missing module using **`npm install -g @ionic/cli-framework`**. After that I could successfully run `ionic info` again.
Therefor I guess it's an unresolved dependency issue inside the `@ionic/cli-plugin-proxy` module.

Comment: Thank you. That resolved my second error so I deleted it from my original forum question. Do you happen to know how to answer my first issue? Please see above.

Comment: Does a normal `ionic build <your target platform>` fail too? And with a code sign error as well?  
Then check if your app id in config.xml is the same as your bundle identifier. If it's a CodeSign error, it's most likely something is wrong with your profiles.  Maybe trying to create new ones solves the issue.